# Numbers as column names of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, names

Is there a reason why R won't allow me to have a number as the column name of my dataframe?

Also noticed that if i do `data.frame(XX)` it adds an `X` to all the column headers that have numbers at the front.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, because R won't allow names of objects to start with numbers. If you were to call `attach()` with the data.frame, this would cause some issues.

`data.frame` (and `read.table`) function has the `check.names` parameter (default is `TRUE`)

> If `TRUE` then the names of the variables in the data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names and are not duplicated. If necessary they are adjusted (by `make.names`) so that they are.

From `?make.names`:

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number. [...] The character "`X`" is prepended if necessary.

Answer (score 32):

Works for me

```
data.frame(`1`=rnorm(3), `2`=head(letters,3), check.names=FALSE)
#        1 2
# 1 0.5019 a
# 2 1.1148 b
# 3 0.4787 c
```

Comment: thanks. I understood about numbers, but it seems that some unicode text is disallowed. When I'm using a frame just for formatting, your suggestion comes in handy.